# How to pin/unpin Microsoft Edge developer tools in Windows 10

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-10, ie-developer-tools, microsoft-edge

I have upgraded to Windows 10; had a great experience on installation process. But very strange thing is I am not finding a way to pin (ctrl+9 for IE) the Developer Tools to an existing window with the MS Edge browser app. Is it missing?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct, pinning/unpinning the F12 developers is not available in current builds of Microsoft Edge (10240). This is a known issue and we are planning to bring it back in a future update.

Comment: 9.11.2015 - still nothing. Are there any updates on this problem? Or it's coming™?

Comment: It's still not there in the latest Edge.

Answer (score 2):

**In my laptop**, the Microsoft Edge has it pinned. And the icon with the shoutcut (Ctrl+P) is back too.

> Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0
>
> Microsoft EdgeHTML 13.10586

And **in my desktop** it's still missing, but looking at the version...

> Microsoft Edge 20.10240.16384.0

Both PCs are fully updated, but the thing is that in the Desktop I'm getting Insider Preview updates, and in the laptop I'm not.